# Why does an error occurs only on heroku server? (Python code)

Tags: python, heroku, beautifulsoup

I've been running the python code which is **scraping** a recent post using BeautifulSoup on a Heroku server. And it had worked well so far.
Suddenly an index error has occurred on below part.

```
url = soup.select('#flagList > div.clear.ab-webzine > div > a')             
latest_url = url[0] <- error occured hear
```

I'd checked the scraping site and found out some css has changed as below.
`#flagList > div > div > a`
Before modifying the css in the code on heroku server, I've tried running it in VSCode locally on computer.
And the original code works good as always.
However, I fixed the csss to make sure the error did not occur and tested it locally. The result was fine as before.
So I upload it on heroku server(Deployment method is Github), but the index error occurred again on same part.
I don't know why the error suddenly occurs, although the code runs fine on my computer.

Comment: What is `href`? You haven't shown where it comes from, but I suggest you take a look at its value. Lots of sites don't _like_ being scraped, and have systems in place to thwart this kind of thing. You might not be getting the same payload on Heroku as you are getting on your dev machine.

Comment: @Chris Oh, it is `url` not href. I edited. And I don't think scraping is blocked, because as I know, that site admin is tolerant of scraping.

Comment: @vantabeam this might be because sometimes sites send data specific to a region. Say you are testing from Asia and the heroku server is deployed in US. In that case the site may return a geography specific response. Kindly check with proxies in your local system for validating this theory. Also, for scraping related issue try to provide the site url you are trying to scrape and possibly code to test it out. Just snippets without context or log trace does not help a lot.